# How to define list of secret items projected in volume via terraform

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-secrets

My intention is to create a k8s Job via terraform.

In process I need to create volumes and project list of secret item in it.

i am able to achieve that via following snippet of yaml config

```
  volumeMounts:
  - name: certs
    mountPath: /app/certs
  - name: ca-certs
    mountPath: /app/ca-certs
volumes:
- name: certs
  secret:
      secretName: "tls-cert-internal"
      items:
      - key: tls.crt
        path: crt.pem
      - key: tls.key
        path: key.pem
- name: ca-certs
  secret:
      secretName: ca-bundle
      items:
      - key: tls.crt
        path: ca_crt.pem
```

however i like to create it using terraform which I try as

```
resource "kubernetes_job" "xxx" {
  metadata {
    name      = "xxxxx"
    namespace = "test"
  }
  wait_for_completion = true

  spec {
    template {
      metadata {}
      spec {
        container {
          name              = "test"
          image             =  "test"
          image_pull_policy = "Always"
          volume_mount {
            name = "certs"
            mount_path = "/app/certs"
          }
          volume_mount {
            name = "ca-certs"
            mount_path = "/app/ca-certs"
          }

        volume {
         name = "certs"
         secret {
           secret_name = "tls-cert-internal"
           items =  [
              {
                 key = tls.crt
                 path = crt.pem
              },
              {
                 key = tls.key
                 path= key.pem
              }
            ]
         } 
       }

        volume {
        name = "ca-certs"
        secret {
          secret_name = "ca-bundle"
          items = [
              {
                 key = tls.crt
                 path = tls.crt
              }
          ]            
    
       }
       }
     }
```

However it fails as :

```
on xxxxx, in resource "kubernetes_job" "xxx":
 :             items =  [

An argument named "items" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block
of type "items"?
```

I tired following this https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/pod#secret

However seems like I am not providing incorrect syntax. kindly guide me for same

Comment: You can try the following: `items {
                 key = tls.crt
                 path = tls.crt
              }`

Comment: @Marcin How to define multiple items here it works when I define it like
items { 
           key = tls.crt
           path tls.crt
        }

However I need to define multiple items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can have multiple `items` blocks:

```
        secret {

          secret_name = "ca-bundle"

          items {
                 key = tls.crt
                 path = tls.crt
              }

          items {
                 key = tls2.crt
                 path = tls2.crt
              }
       }
```